# Write console.time result to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to write `console.time()` result to variable?

```
console.time('It\'s saved!');
fn();
var a = console.timeEnd('It\'s saved!');
console.log(a) // => It's saved!: 16ms
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, but you can use [`window.performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) instead

```
var t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Lt250wa/

Answer (score 11):

I know that the question is a bit old but now you can use [performance Api](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_now) in Node.js:

```
const {performance} = require('perf_hooks');
const start = performance.now();
fn();
const end = performance.now();
console.log(`${end - start}ms`);
```

or use `timerify()`:

```
const {
  performance,
  PerformanceObserver
} = require('perf_hooks');

function fn() {
 // some stuff here
}

const wrapped = performance.timerify(fn);

const obs = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
  console.log(list.getEntries()[0].duration);
  obs.disconnect();
});
obs.observe({ entryTypes: ['function'] });

// A performance timeline entry will be created
wrapped();
```

**Note: the performance api was added in Node v8.5.0.**